# Faster nested for-loop, perhaps using pd.groupby

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, pandas-groupby

I have a nested loop. But my data set is very large, so I need a faster way. I believe it can be done with grouping or mapping the data in some clever way.
I have a list of X Names. For each Name, I have items that consist of Color, Brand and a Value.
I need to sum the Values for each combination of Color and Brand for each Name. Then do some operations on these sums, within each Color at first, then within each Name, while keeping track on the combination over which the sum is computed.
The nested for-loop becomes very slow, as my data set is large.
Is there a faster way?

```
import random
import pandas
list1 = ['Name 0']
list2 = ['Color 0']
list3 = ['Brand 0']
list4 = [random.randint(10,1000)]
nName = 25
nColor = 5
nBrand = 3
nSim = 1000
for i in range(1,nSim):
    list1.extend(['Name {}'.format(random.randint(0,nName))])
    list2.extend(['Color {}'.format(random.randint(0,nColor))])
    list3.extend(['Brand {}'.format(random.randint(0, nBrand))])
    list4.append(random.randint(10,1000))
d = list(zip(list1, list2, list3, list4))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Name','Color','Brand','Value'])

end_values = np.zeros(nName)
for iName in range(0,nName):
    y = 0
    for iColor in range(0,nColor):
        x = np.zeros(nBrand)
        for iBrand in range(0,nBrand):
            x[iBrand] = np.nansum(df1[((df1['Name'] == 'Name {}'.format(iName)) & (df1['Color'] == 'Color {}'.format(iColor)) & (df1['Brand'] == 'Brand {}'.format(iBrand)))]['Value'])
        y = y + x[0] + 1.5 * x[1] + 3 * x[0] * x[2]
    end_values[iName] = y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what your problem actually is. Because there are no nested for-loops in the code you have provided in the question. Do you mean nested loops over all the combinations of `Name`, `Color`, and `Brand` values? If so you don't need to write any loops. Just use `pandas` means:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['Name', 'Color', 'Brand']).agg({'Value': 'sum'})
```

Yes, a single line to compute them all. Like `group by` in SQL. For example, `num22` is `df2.loc[('Name 0', 'Color 2', 'Brand 2'), 'Value']`.

In case of a little bit more complex calculations

```
df3 = df1.groupby(['Name', 'Color', 'Brand']).agg({'Value': ['count', 'sum']})
```

`num22` is `df3.loc[('Name 0', 'Color 2', 'Brand 2'), ('Value', 'sum')]`.

`.agg(...)`'s argument is a dictionary where you specify what columns you wanna treat and what statistics you wanna get.

Try this way and tell if I'm misunderstanding your problem.

**EDIT**

Consider the following code:

```
# 1. original code with nested loops
# includes slight correction (+1 in range(...) and zeros(...) functions)
def f_1(df1):
    end_values = np.zeros(nName + 1)
    for iName in range(nName + 1):
        y = 0
        for iColor in range(nColor + 1):
            x = np.zeros(nBrand + 1)
            for iBrand in range(nBrand + 1):
                x[iBrand] = np.nansum(df1[((df1['Name'] == 'Name {}'.format(iName)) & (df1['Color'] == 'Color {}'.format(iColor)) & (df1['Brand'] == 'Brand {}'.format(iBrand)))]['Value'])
            y = y + x[0] + 1.5 * x[1] + 3 * x[0] * x[2]
        end_values[iName] = y
    return end_values

# 3. new code - supportive function to calculate result for brands
def f_2_suppport(srs):
    cnt = {k: v for k, v in zip(srs.index.get_level_values(2), srs)}
    a = cnt.get('Brand 0', 0)
    b = cnt.get('Brand 1', 0)
    c = cnt.get('Brand 2', 0)
    return a + 1.5 * b + 3 * a * c

# 2. new code - main function with pandas groupby/agg
def f_2(df1):

    return (
        df1
        .groupby(['Name', 'Color', 'Brand'])
        .agg({'Value': 'sum'})
        .groupby(['Name', 'Color'])
        .agg({'Value': lambda x: f_2_suppport(x)})
        .groupby('Name')
        .agg({'Value': 'sum'}))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(f_1(df1))
    print(f_2(df1))
```

Output:

```
[28735057.  26111382.  28304153.5 15495841.  15915862.5 13884354.5
 21172873.  27342470.5 29403143.  38212958.5 37504605. ]
              Value
Name               
Name 0   28735057.0
Name 1   26111382.0
Name 10  37504605.0
Name 2   28304153.5
Name 3   15495841.0
Name 4   15915862.5
Name 5   13884354.5
Name 6   21172873.0
Name 7   27342470.5
Name 8   29403143.0
Name 9   38212958.5
```

Runnign time on my machine:

```
%timeit f_1(df1)
1.07 s ± 736 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit f_2(df1)
35.2 ms ± 163 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So `groupby` + `agg` make calculation about 30 times faster.

Comment: I have not written the loops in code, but the logic is as follows:

For every name:
(For every color:
(For every brand: sum up values and make an operation of these three numbers)
sum up the return from inner loop and make an operation of these five numbers)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
The code seems to do the work. And I save a lot of time. I had nName = 1500 as well, so that took me like 20 minutes. It's done within seconds now.